# How to define Generic for a function with specified keyword arguments?

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to create a generic for functions with keyword arguments, something like this:

```py
# Not valid code
class Args(TypedDict):
    a: str
    b: int

foo: KWFunc[Args, dict] # Equivalent to (a: str, b: int) -> dict
```

As non-generic, this could be achieved via Protocol:

```py
R = TypeVar('R')
class KWFunc(Protocol[R]):
    def __call__(self, a: str, b: int) -> R:
        pass

foo: KWFunc[dict] # Equivalent to (a: str, b: int) -> dict
```

Also, It is possible to create a generic for function with positional arguments:

```py
R = TypeVar('R')
P = ParamSpec('P')

class KWFunc(Protocol[P, R]):
    def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> R:
        pass

foo: KWFunc[[str, int], dict] # Equivalent to (str, int) -> dict
```

Is there a way to define generic type for function with keyword arguments as parameter?

Comment: Small note: your last example defines `typing.Callable`. In short, what you want to implement is not supported yet, unfortunately: [mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4441), [pep about tuple unpacking (mentions that nothing for **kwargs is done)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/)